# iOS - Calculating the area and perimeter of a region on maps

Tags: ios, maps

In my app there's a satellite view for a map which will show some vacant lands, buildings, playgrounds etc. If user wants to measure the size of the playground (which has no straight border), so for that user will select the how can I measure the area & perimeter. There's [an app which calculates](http://chssystems.com/LandArea.html) similar to the one that I'm looking for

Any ideas of algorithms available?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are asking, but of the user specifies the area in particular you can register the points on the map and use the "distanceFromPoint" method to calculate the perimeter. I can look up the exact method when I'm on my computer.

Comment: Calculating "distanceFromPoint" for all the points on map won't give the perimeter or area. There might be some algorithm for that.